# What will take less time: reading multiple files or merging contents into a large file?

Tags: c++, file, csv

I am in need to open and manipulate data present in many files, which are found in multiple folders. We're speaking of approximately 500k files which hold around 5Gb of numeric data.

I have worked with that data, but it takes around an hour to run semi-simple algorithms. 
I was wondering if the process of changing the address of the files would be the most time consuming operation... (because I have to do loops where I concatenate the folders/files numbers I want to access).
I am doing a merge of all the raw data into a single file (with a file ID) in the hope it takes less time to go through all the raw data...

Am I correct in this assumption? It will take me quite a lot of time to do this.
I am doing this with c++.
Thanks for any input

@Thomas:Thanks for the suggestions. I'm adding multiple buffers, it's already showing promising signs. I will for sure start threads for each of the tasks.
I will try to make my arrays around 1 Mb of size, to see if it really speed things up. All of the buffers are global vars, so it should be okay...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, reading in files is one of the primary bottlenecks for performance.  So, let's start there.

### Optimizing File Reading

The best method for optimizing reading of input files is to reduce the number of input requests and expand the quantity of data per request.  So, rather than reading in one value at a time, read a block of values with one read statement.

**Block Reading**
I suggest reading data in large chunks (1Mb) into memory, then extract your data from the buffer.  You'll need to consider the case when data spans the end of the buffer to a new buffer.

**Memory mapping the file**
Some OSes have functions to treat the file as an array of bytes in memory.  The OS handles the loading of data into memory for you.  This is not standard C++, and depends on the OS.

**Multiple threads, one for reading**
Another solution is to use multiple threads, at least two.  One of the threads has the task of reading data into a buffer and notifying the other thread that data is ready.  The OS could delegate the reading thread to another core, allowing the other core to perform the computations.

**Double & Multiple buffering**
Expanding on the multiple threads, use multiple data buffers.  The "reading" thread will be reading into one buffer, while the other thread is pulling data from a different buffer.  The idea is to use as much buffering to reduce the amount of waiting of the computation thread.

**Changing data format**
Fixed length records are faster to read than variable length records.  So if the data is only numbers, use fixed width fields.

If the data is read multiple times, consider reading the files once and writing new files that are in binary (raw, non-textual) format.  Read from this file for the 2nd and more iterations, which removes the need to convert from textual format to internal format.

Comment: Although parsing numbers from a data buffer is waaay faster than the data from the file is pouring in (as you said, bottleneck is the reading speed). Fixed length entries have a different advantage: you can compute the offset of specific data in the file.

Comment: Numbers in fixed with can be easier read into a buffer without having issues of the data crossing from one buffer to another. :-)

Comment: The bottleneck is **not** bandwidth ("reading speed"). The bottleneck is first and foremost seek/access time as well as traversing the directory hierarchy and opening/closing files. Bandwidth is upwards of 100 MB/s on a low-end spinning disk drive, and upwards of 500 MB/s on SSDs. Opening 500k files takes time. Also, reading small amounts of data that is not block-sized wastes both bandwidth and buffer space. The hardware can only ever read and transfer a complete block at a time, so if you have a lot of small files, there will inevitably be a lot of data loaded that you're not going to use.

Comment: Good point regarding lots of small files being bad for seek time. @ThomasMatthews now compare the 500 MB/s you get off of a hard disc to the ~50 GB/s you have off of a cache: you can do 100's of operations on your data till you reach the reading speed of the hard drive - the copy from one, small read buffer to your final data buffer is peanuts - different story if the memory of the file is already mapped into physical memory though!

Comment: @Damon: The bottleneck is getting the data from the file to the memory of the program.  This includes but is not limited to the following factor:  ramping time (to get the motor up to speed), time to seek to a physical sector, track location time, data transfer rate from platter to hard drive cache, data transfer from hard drive data cache to platform (example, via PATA interface), buffering times by devices drivers and OS, time to look up the filename in the drive directory, and # of entries in the hard drive directory.

Comment: Files contain at least one block each, 500k files means 500k blocks (at least). Assuming they are not all contiguous and accessed in the correct order by _sheer coincidence_, that is 1 hour 6 minutes spent seeking at 8ms per access. On the other hand, reading 5GB of contiguous data merely takes around 50 seconds on a below-average disk. This doesn't even take into account traversing the directory structure and access checking 500k files when opening them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a hard and fast answer to your question.  If you're trying to access the data whole sale (i.e. you're not picking and choosing specific chunks of data/files) I would think that if you had all the data in one location would be faster.

If every time you're running your algorithm you only want specific information, and the files let you access only that information, I would stick with the structure you currently have.

The other thing to consider is how often are you running this process?  Are you running on the same information?  If you're doing a one off analysis I would suggest just leaving it, even if it does take more time.  If this is a routine you're going to run regularly, and again you want do it on all of the information, it might be worth grouping your data into one large set

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will surely make a deeper analysis of that data. My biggest fear is leaving the pc running and the return being the program runs 5 minutes faster.

Answer (score 1):

Every file access has an overhead. The system will need to look up its physical location before being able to access it.
If you avoid that lookup, its a little bit of overhead your shave off.
If you can put your data on the file in the order it will be needed, you will certainly see a more dramatic speedup, specially if using conventional hard drives. If you are using SSDs and have a lot of RAM for cache, the improvement will not be as dramatic.
If you can access your data in large blocks, you will see benefits. If your computation requires random access to your data you may be better off increasing RAM for disk cache or buying an SSD.